# MySQL GROUP function changing Character Set

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Our current database is MySQL 5.1 which serves a number of Delphi and Web-based applications. The database is setup with the defaults of the time so the tables are all set to be `latin1`.

We are seeing an odd problem where when one of our tables is queried with no `Group` functions applied to it, the results return as `utf8`, however when applying a `Group` the result comes back as `latin1` when viewing the Field Types in Workbench.

An example:
`SELECT jb_numb, jb_name FROM job WHERE jb_numb = 1234`
returns
[image: Result of SELECT with no GROUP]

However
`SELECT jb_numb, jb_name FROM job WHERE jb_numb = 1234 GROUP BY jb_numb`
yields
[image: Result of SELECT with GROUP]

Workbench displays the result of both queries the sameon the Result Grid, however the results will, understandably, display differently when returned to the front-ends.

Has anyone else come accross this issue, and if so is there a solution (Other than a switch to newer version of MySQL/utf 8 which is in the planning)

Comment: Just for the record, UTF8 is on the way out in favor of  UTF8MB4 standard, so if you are  modifying the tables, you might consider doing this at the same time to future proof.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in MySQL 5.1. You can try to CAST, but a better solution would be to update your server.

Comment: without it being a bug, 5.1 is old, and update is recommended, @slaakso: Do you have a reference to this bug?

Comment: Thanks. That's what we were starting to think. I'm pushing to accelerate the upgrade.